# Passing cython classes to function in .pyx

Tags: python, cython

I've declared a class in Cython that needs to be passed into a separate function to be imported from Python. This is possible with `cdef` but not `def` as Cython cannot convert Python object to my class type.

In code, what I'm trying to do is:

```
cdef extern from "myClass.h"
    cdef cppclass C_myClass "myClass":
        void C_myClass(float*, int*, int*)

    void _increment(C_myClass, float)

cdef class myClass:
...
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # so far, so good...
    def some_other_util(self):
        # you get the gist

def increment(C_myClass obj, float value): # cdef not recognisable from Python!
    _increment(obj, value)
    return
```

Is there preferred method for passing in a custom class to a cython function from Python?

Comment: Regular Cython extension types (classes) are, by default, importable from Python, so you just have to replace `C_myClass obj` for `myClass obj`, and the `increment` function should work. The thing that I don't understand (maybe I am missing something) is, if a `myClass` object is not a valid argument for `_increment` how do you intend to call it from a Python script?

Comment: @alfonsoSR You understood correctly, thanks. But if I do 
`def increment(myClass obj, float value):` then underneath `_increment(<C_myClass*> &obj, value)`.
Gives me:
`Cannot take address of Python variable 'obj'`

Comment: I have never used Cython to work with C++, so I cannot help with this one. Maybe you can find some more info here: [Using C++ in Cython](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html). Anyway, you should consider rephrasing your question, as it seems to say: "I want to pass an extension type as an argument for a `def` function inside a `.pyx` file", and that isn't what you are trying to do.

Comment: Presumably `myClass` has the `C_myClass` as a `cdef` member? You want to take the address of that. You should also almost never use `<C_myClass*>` casts - if you don't know exactly what you're doing they're a very good way to stop the compiler tell you when you've made a mistake.

Comment: @DavidW yes, I have `cdef C_myClass* ptr_myClass` as an attribute defined inside `myClass`... ah yes - `_increment(obj.ptr_myClass, value)` has worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @DavidW, I managed to fix this. I used the `cdef C_myClass* ptr_myClass` defined in `myclass` to pass the argument:

```
cdef extern from "myClass.h"
    cdef cppclass C_myClass "myClass":
        void C_myClass(float*, int*, int*)

    void _increment(C_myClass, float)

cdef class myClass:
    cdef C_myClass* ptr_myClass
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # so far, so good...
    def some_other_util(self):
        # you get the gist

def increment(C_myClass obj, float value): # cdef not recognisable from Python!
    _increment(obj.ptr_myClass, value)
    return
```